# Calculate 95th percentile of values with grouping variable

Tags: excel, r, variables, grouping

I'm trying to calculate the 95th percentile for multiple water quality values grouped by watershed, for example:

```
Watershed   WQ
50500101    62.370661
50500101    65.505046
50500101    58.741477
50500105    71.220034
50500105    57.917249
```

I reviewed this question posted - Percentile for Each Observation w/r/t Grouping Variable.  It seems very close to what I want to do but it's for EACH observation. I need it for each grouping variable. so ideally,

```
Watershed   WQ - 95th
50500101    x
50500105    y
```

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved using the `plyr` library. We specify the grouping variable `Watershed` and ask for the 95% quantile of WQ.

```
library(plyr)
#Random seed
set.seed(42)
#Sample data
dat <- data.frame(Watershed = sample(letters[1:2], 100, TRUE), WQ = rnorm(100))
#plyr call
ddply(dat, "Watershed", summarise, WQ95 = quantile(WQ, .95))
```

and the results

```
  Watershed     WQ95
    1         a 1.353993
    2         b 1.461711
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `daply`, since the results nicely condense to an array, e.g., `daply(dat, .(Watershed), function(x) quantile(x$WQ, 0.95))`.

Comment: Data frames are usually easier to work with in terms of future aggregations and joining back to the original data

Answer (score 7):

I hope I understand your question correctly. Is this what you're looking for?

```
my.df <- data.frame(group = gl(3, 5), var = runif(15))
aggregate(my.df$var, by = list(my.df$group), FUN = function(x) quantile(x, probs = 0.95))

  Group.1         x
1       1 0.6913747
2       2 0.8067847
3       3 0.9643744
```

*EDIT*

Based on Vincent's answer,

```
aggregate(my.df$var, by = list(my.df$group), FUN = quantile, probs  = 0.95)
```

also works (you can skin a cat 1001 ways - I've been told). A side note, you can specify a vector of desired -iles, say `c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3...)` for deciles. Or you can try function `summary` for some predefined statistics.

```
aggregate(my.df$var, by = list(my.df$group), FUN = summary)
```

Comment: and I had never used gl before... :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a combination of the tapply and quantile functions. For example, if your dataset looks like this:

```
DF <- data.frame('watershed'=sample(c('a','b','c','d'), 1000, replace=T), wq=rnorm(1000))
```

Use this:

```
with(DF, tapply(wq, watershed, quantile, probs=0.95))
```

Comment: Richie: is that 'with' edit really an improvement? I don't mind it, but I'm just wondering if you just find it more elegant that way or if there's an actual technical benefit.

Comment: I find it a matter of taste, although it may have its advantages if you want it a bit more dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, you're going to want to use an array formula to make this easy.  I suggest the following:

```
{=PERCENTILE(IF($A2:$A6 = Watershed ID, $B$2:$B$6), 0.95)}
```

Column A would be the Watershed ids, and Column B would be the WQ values.

Also, be sure to enter the formula as an array formula.  Do so by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering the formula.

Comment: Plug in the value for Watershed ID.  That was just a placeholder.  For instance     {=PERCENTILE(IF($A2:$A6 = 50500101, $B$2:$B$6), 0.95)}

Comment: If you use a cell reference for the Watershed ID, you can fill down the formula for all IDs in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki)-package you can do:

```
set.seed(42)
#Sample data
dt <- data.table(Watershed = sample(letters[1:2], 100, TRUE), WQ = rnorm(100))

dt[ ,
    j = .(WQ95 = quantile(WQ, .95, na.rm = TRUE),
    by = Watershed]
```